# bitcoin transaction stuck on bitcoin.com

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, blockchain

transaction id - https://mempool.space/tx/af483ce44a4605a9f13faf66d37e42f574377f7a7723ada51c01f4b98aebdcca I did transaction on bitcoin.com but 28hours ago transaction pending and money deducted I am the sender and I am the receiver also.. please help me